# Passing options_for_select values from a model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having a drop down in my rails application as below.

```
= form_tag({:controller=>"r4c", :action=>"result"}, method: :get) do
 = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
 = select_tag(:q, options_for_select([["Single load completed trip", "r4c_001"]]), class:"select")
 = submit_tag("Get Test Details")
```

As we can see, i am passing the value [["Single....]] value directly into the options_for_select. I am trying to fetch this value from another class say a model and i have created a model class.

```
require 'active_record'
class R4cOptionsModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 def country_options
    return [["Single load completed trip", "r4c_001"]]
 end
end
```

and the view form to

```
= select_tag(:q, options_for_select(R4cOptionsModel.country_options), class:"select")
```

but i am getting a error message as

> undefined method `country_options' for #

What is the correct approach to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You try to use `country_options` method as a class method, yet you defined it as an instance method.

Comment: Instead of making it a method, how to make it as a static variable of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `country_options` is defined as instance method in class `R4cOptionsModel`. So, either call it on an object of this class in the view:

```
= select_tag(:q, options_for_select(@r4c_option_model.country_options), class:"select")
```

Or, better if your options are more static, define the method as a class method using `self`:

```
class R4cOptionsModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.country_options
    [["Single load completed trip", "r4c_001"]]
  end
end
```

... and keep view code as is.

### Update

#### Define it in helper method (Recommended)

Use this approach if you need these option values only in views. Define it in `ApplicationHelper` or any other helper module.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def country_options
    [["Single load completed trip", "r4c_001"]]
  end
end
```

and in views:

```
= select_tag(:q, options_for_select(country_options), class:"select")
```

Comment: how to define it as a static variable instead of a static method

Comment: Will these option values be static?

Comment: Then, please use the second approach. Define it as a class method.

Comment: I tried that and i am getting undefined method `country_options' for nil:NilClass. Update: this worked = select_tag(:q, options_for_select(R4cOptionsModel.country_options), class:"select")

Comment: Please check the recommended approach

Comment: Yes it worked and i think the recommended approach is the clean one. since we are just going to use the values and no other logics, can we keep it as a variable in Application helper? I changed the code to "module ApplicationHelper
  country_options = [["Single load completed trip", "r4c_001"]]
end" but i am getting "undefined local variable or method `country_options' for #<#<Class:0x00007f49264a26a0>:0x00007f49264a0f58>"

Comment: You should define it as a method like `def country_options ... end`. In your shown code you are missing `def` keyword.